# Freehub with sealed/cartridge bearings

Tags: mountain-bike, rear-wheel, bearings, freehub

I decided to buy a new freehub and replace it myself, as the one I had broke down (started spinning to both sides). However, I didn't realize the new freehub has sealed/cartridge bearings as opposed to the old one which had loose bearings... as I was doing this for the first time I didn't even notice.

What can I use instead of the old cone that used to secure the loose bearings?

On the other side I still have the loose bearings system. Will this work or can it cause any future troubles?

[image: freehub]

[image: freehub with cone and lock nut]

Comment: I would say you've bought the wrong part, sorry.  Either take it back and swap, or its new-hub time, which may mean a new complete wheel is cheaper than a new hub + rebuild.  Good luck!